# clicking an option in dynamic popup window dropdown in testcafe

Tags: javascript, ui-automation, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have been trying to choose `Ab`from the dynamic popup window with `dropdown` class.

```
<div class="dropdown hideonly clone" id="ddm_continue"
 style="left: 547.633px; top: 265px; width: 99.1562px; display: block;">

<ul>
    <li onclick="continueTransaction(944, 2)">Ab</li>
<li onclick="continueTransaction(944, 3)">Bc</li>
<li onclick="continueTransaction(944, 4)">De</li>
<li onclick="continueTransaction(944, 14)">Ef</li>
<li onclick="continueTransaction(944, 13)">Gh</li>
<li onclick="duplicateTransaction(944, 1)">Ij</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

so far I did try many options including

```
this.chooseAb = Selector('.dropdown');
this.ab = Selector(this.chooseAb.child(0));
this.ab1 = Selector(this.ab.child(0)).withText('Ab');
```

No Success! Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```js
this.dropdown = Selector('#ddm_continue');
this.ul = this.dropdown.find('ul');
this.ab = this.ul.withText('Ab');
```